# Currently I am on Lesson: 9 of PatrickCollins Course- Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'

Tags: solidity, web3js

Could someone please help me understand and resolve the following error in my code?

Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'
[image: Error]

Here is the Raffle.test.js

```
const { network, getNamedAccounts, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Raffle", async () => {
          let deployer, raffle, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, raffleEntranceFee, interval
          const chainId = network.config.chainId

          beforeEach(async () => {
              deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
              await deployments.fixture(["all"])

              const myContract = await deployments.get("Raffle")
              raffle = await ethers.getContractAt(myContract.abi, myContract.address)

              vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await deployments.get("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
              vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt(
                  vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.abi,
                  vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
              )
              raffleEntranceFee = await raffle.getEntranceFee()
              interval = await raffle.getInterval()
          })

          describe("constructor", async () => {
              it("Initializes the raffle correctly", async () => {
                  // Ideally we make our test have just 1 assert per "it"
                  const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState() // Must be open
                  assert.equal(raffleState.toString(), "0")

                  const interval = await raffle.getInterval()
                  assert.equal(interval.toString(), networkConfig[chainId]["interval"])
              })
          })

          describe("enterRaffle", async () => {
              it("reverts when you don't pay enough", async () => {
                  await expect(raffle.enterRaffle()).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(
                      raffle,
                      "Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered"
                  )
              })

              it("records players when they enter", async () => {
                  await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                  const playerFromContract = await raffle.getPlayer(0)
                  assert.equal(playerFromContract, deployer)
              })

              it("emits events on enter", async () => {
                  await expect(raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })).to.emit(
                      raffle,
                      "RaffleEnter"
                  )
              })

              it("doesn't allow entrance when raffle is calculating", async () => {
                  await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                  await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [Number(interval) + 1])
                  await network.provider.send("evm_mine", [])

                  
                  await raffle.performUpkeep("0x")

                  // Assert: Attempt to enter the raffle again and expect it to fail
                  await expect(
                      raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                  ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(raffle, "Raffle__NotOpen")
              })
          })
      })
```

Here is Raffle.sol -

```
// Raffle

// Enter the lottery (paying some amount)
// Pick a random winner (verifiably random)
// Winner to be selected every X minutes -> completely automated

// Chainlink Oracle -> Randomness, Automated Execution (Chainlink Keepers)

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/AutomationCompatible.sol";

error Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
error Raffle__TransferredFailed();
error Raffle__NotOpen();
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

/** @title A simple raffle contract
 * @author Hrithik
 * @notice This contract is for creating untamperable decentralized smart contract
 * @dev This implements Chainlink VRF v2 and Chainlink Automation
 */

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    /* Types declarations */
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    } // This is how enum works internally -> (uint256 0 = OPEN, 1 = CALCULATING)

    /* State Variables*/
    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionID;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    // Lottery Variables
    address private s_recentWinner;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;

    /* Events */
    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    /* Functions */
    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionID,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionID = subscriptionID;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
        }

        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__NotOpen();
        }

        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
        // Emit an event whenever we update a dyanmic array or mapping

        // convention for naming events is to reverse the function name
        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that the Chainlink Automation Node call
     * they look for the `upKeepNeeded' to return true
     * The Following should be true to return true
     * 1. Our time interval should have passed.
     * 2. The lottery should have at least 1 player and have some ETH
     * 3. Our subscription is funded with LINK.
     * 4. The lottery should be in an "open" state
     */

    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    ) public view override returns (bool upKeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;

        upKeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        (bool upKeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upKeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }

        // Chainlink VRF is a two step process:
        // 1. Request a random number
        // 2. Once we get it, do something with it
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane, // gasLane
            i_subscriptionID,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );

        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 /* requestId */,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;

        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN; // Reset Raffle State
        s_players = new address payable[](0); // Reset Players Array after picking the winner
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;

        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferredFailed();
        }

        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    /* View / Pure functions */

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_entranceFee;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentWinner;
    }

    function getRaffleState() public view returns (RaffleState) {
        return s_raffleState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return NUM_WORDS; // Since NUM_WORDS is in the byte code, we can't read it from storage,
    } // so we make the function pure instead of view

    function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }

    function getLatestTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }
}
```

I'm happy to provide more details if needed. I would really appreciate any guidance. Thank you!